# Using BulkCopy with Powerhsell SQL SMO

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I am using SQL Server Management Objects(SMO) with PowerShell to connect to a MSSQL DB and run some queries. The authentication uses Windows auth so I can't use `sqlclient`.

For a part of it I use loops with individual `INSERT` statements to insert data into a table.

Using `BulkCopy` should be a lot faster and easier. But I couldn't find any documentation for it. I found some results about C# so I am thinking if it is possible in PowerShell?

Comment: So what is the code you're having trouble with here? The only qusetion you ask is *"I am thinking if it is possible in PowerShell?"* which is simply a "Yes/No" question; probably yes. What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? What is the code you already have, and why isn't it working?

Comment: `SqlClient` can be used with Windows Auth. You just have to setup the connection string correctly and make sure your code is being executed in the context of a Windows/AD user that has permissions to connect to the database.

Comment: @SaiPuli Thank you, you are right, I managed to get `SqlClient` working with Windows auth. Had to add `Integrated Security=true;` to the connection string.